# JDBC not updating sqlite table at specific column

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I've encountered this very strange behaviour, where I construct a string to update a row of a table such as the following:

```
sql = "UPDATE cosmetics SET trail = 4,color = '[blue]',doTrail = 0,trails = null,trailSeen = null,inventory = null,uuid = 'abcd' WHERE uuid = 'abcd'";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
```

In a try catch, and the code runs fine.

My issue is everything *but* the first column mentioned(ie, trail in this case) is updated. If I check the table from sqlite with:

```
SELECT * FROM cosmetics WHERE uuid = 'abcd';
```

It returns

```
uuid|trail|doTrail|color|inventory|trails|trailSeen
abcd|0|0|[blue]|||
```

where previously, the value was:

```
uuid|trail|doTrail|color|inventory|trails|trailSeen
abcd|0|1|[white]|||
```

So doTrail was updated, and so was color, the only thing not updated was trail. I have no idea why this is, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the `.schema cosmetics`

```
CREATE TABLE cosmetics (uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, trail INTEGER, doTrail BOOLEAN, color TEXT DEFAULT "[white]", inventory TEXT, trails TEXT, trailSeen TEXT);
```

I should also mention if I copy and paste the value of `sql` directly into a terminal, there are no issues and the table is updated as expected.

Comment: What is the type of `trail`? It may help to show the definition of table `cosmetics`.

Comment: @HenningKoehler I added the info in an edit

Comment: There goes my idea that it was a type issue. But just to be sure, one thing you could test is what happens if trail is set to some value other than 0 before you run the update, just in case it does perform an update but to 0 (the default) instead of 4.